# Send ctrl+q to excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, file, com

I have an excel file that I need to press ctrl+q to make a vba code(macro) to run.
is there a way to do this with python?
someting like:

```
with open (my_file,"wb")
    "press ctrl+q"
    close file
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the open command is for opening a file and manipulating it's raw content - not suitable for your need

the are are modules for reading and writing excel files like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/), but they don't include running vba macros. if the macro functionality can be implemented in python, this will probably be a good start.

If you need to run macros, you need to interact with an instance of excel using com automation (so you need to have it locally installed) - the [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) module can be a good start

Answer (score 1):

I built a macro that starts when I open the file and add it to a template.
I created my new files with the template (using panda) and when I open them- the macro runs alone,

Thanks All!